# How to secure a Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring-boot, rest, authentication, groovy, spring-security

How do I secure my Spring REST API? I would like clients (On other domains/apps) to login/register to my API via google OAuth2 or simple username & password in a POST request and for my API to then return something they can use to authenticate following requests to secured endpoints.
I'm having a hard time finding solutions, I have kinda improvised a registration/login
with the following class.
My problems are 2:

1. I'm returning a cookie JSESSIONID which is going to a client on another domain, or a mobile app, what else could I return and how do I configure that?
2. Spring auto-generates login and logout pages, I don't need them since the app is just a REST API web service

```
@Order(2)
    @Configuration
    static class ResourceSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        UserService userService

        @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider


        /**
         * Initialize the daoAuthenticationProvider
         */
        @PostConstruct
        void init() {
            authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider()
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService)
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // Disable auto config
            http.httpBasic().disable()
            // Authentication Provider
            http.authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            http.csrf().disable()
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers('/api/users/auth/**').permitAll()
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").denyAll()
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl('/api/users/auth/login')
            http.logout().logoutUrl('/api/users/logout').invalidateHttpSession(true)

            // Session Management
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)

            // Cors Configuration
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration()
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"))
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"))
            corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", 'OPTIONS'))
            corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"))
            http.cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration)
        }
    }
```

I'm okay with users sending POST requests to /login and /register, but I need to configure something better than a JSESSIONID cookie in my response.

Is there a way to do everything with Google OAuth2? (That'd be optimal, a frontend can just login to Google with the google login react-component and then send me some kind of 'token' I can send to back to Google to verify their identity)

Comment: The [OAuth2 Login sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login) demonstrates how to configure Google for authentication.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, the Login with Google would happen separately inside of another app.
Im not serving any kind of static content a user can navigate, login and get a redirect back to my server with the google auth code

Comment: If you want to use Google as an authorization server and a mobile app as a client, then you can configure your backend as a resource server. See [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html) in the reference docs. In that case, you don't need a login or register endpoint.

Comment: That would be awesome, I have already tried that but failed (with Oauth2 google). I never understood what I need to send to my server from my client. 
I logged into google with a React Component and then got back a huge JSON, I tried to send a request to my resource server with 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>' substituing 'token' with 'acces_token' found in the json response from Google (without any luck), is there any tutorial covering my specific case?

Comment: The Spring Security team does not maintain a react tutorial, sorry.

Comment: it is impossible to answer a question without a running example, stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q&A site, `I have already tried that but failed` will not help anyone, create a question that includes a small example, use debug logs to understand what is wrong, google and read docs.